# How to calculate the count of the results of a formula

Tags: count, crystal-reports, formula

Good day; I am in need of help creating a formula that will only count the results of a formula that = "No". I have written a formula that returns either a Yes or No value, and now I want to count how many values = No. I hope that the wording of the question makes sense.

Comment: Right click on formula... Go to insert summary and take count

Comment: You need to use a Running Total. Give it a try and come back for help if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. The running total did the trick, and now I can put this bad boy into the done folder.